# Divide add and allocate equally and increase if goes into fraction

Tags: excel

i am trying to allocate for e.g. 30 cases to 4 people, here mathematically i can allocate 7*2 and 8*2 and total of 30 cases allocated. but i am trying to do this with excel, i am not able to do so. i have created an excel with numerous use of IF function, it will be helpful if we can do with this an smaller function. I am unable to attach the sheet for reference, i really need to crack this since this is a daily process and the numbers are much higher then 30.

Calculate simple divide :

```
=IF($D12<>"Leave",FLOOR($D$2/(COUNTIF($D$12:$D$19,"In")),1),"Leave")
```

used this to increase # of cases :

```
=IF($D19="In",IF(E20=D2,E20,IF(F18="Leave",IF(F17="Leave",IF(F16="Leave",IF(F15="Leave",IF(F14="Leave",IF(F13="Leave",IF(F12="Leave",E20+1,F12+1),F13+1),F14+1),F15+1),F16+1),F17+1),F18+1)),"Leave")
```

to calculate the new allocation :

```
=IF($D19="Leave","Leave",IF(F19<$H$2,IF(F19=$D$2,IF(F19=$E$20,E19,E19+1),E19+1),E19))
```

Comment: For the"increase if goes to fraction" you could consider roundup(). But an example may help understand what you want ie before and after.

Comment: first : =IF($D12<>"Leave",FLOOR($D$2/(COUNTIF($D$12:$D$19,"In")),1),"Leave")
Calculation : =IF($D12="In",IF($E$20=$D$2,$E$20,$E$20+1),"Leave")
Final : =IF($D12="Leave","Leave",IF(F12<$H$2,IF(F12=$D$2,IF(F12=$E$20,E12,E12+1),E12+1),E12))

$H$2 is D2+1

Comment: Edit your question, show a concrete example. You leave the last function incomplete so make it all clear please. Putting a third version in a comment is not helpful either.

Comment: if anyone can give me any example on how to allocate 30 to 4 people as 8*2 and 7*4 will be great

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gZoKHXlCiSDnISl1ZWjgo7QxgAKLChNE/view?usp=drivesdk ... hope this file helps

Comment: Sorry, don't download files...

Comment: sure no prob. but can you help me to divide 30 into 4 people with some getting 1 more than other.. not sure how best to describe the situation here

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

For the first N-1 people:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(Cases/COUNTA(Person)+ISODD(ROW()),0)
```

For the last person:

```
=Cases-SUM(B5:B8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

List your cases in column **A**.  In **B1** enter:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)
```

and in **B2** enter 4 *(number of people)*.  In **D1** enter:

```
= ROUND(COLUMNS($B:B)/$B$2*$B$1,0)
```

In **E1** enter:

```
=IF(COLUMNS($B:C)<=$B$2,ROUND(COLUMNS($B:C)/$B$2*$B$1,0)-SUM($D$1:D1),"")
```

and this this across.  *(the first row give the number of cases each person gets)*.  In **D2** enter 1.  In **E2** enter:

```
=D2+D1
```

and copy this across.*(the second row supplies indices for `INDEX()`)*

Finally in **D3** enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>D$1,"",INDEX($A:$A,D$2-1+ROWS($1:1)))
```

copy this both down and across:

[image]

**NOTE:**

The core of the answer is in **D1** through **G1**.  It gives the breakdown of number of tasks by available people.

Comment: can you share an example over email. ramandeep.sidana@gmail.com.. sorry for asking to much